# Error to write new file to other application data directory in removable storage using Android SDK 21

Tags: java, android, android-studio, removable-storage

I'm creat an application and need to be able to create new files in a specific directory. But the application fails to create a new file in another directory stored on the **SD-Card** / Removable Disk on Android. I wrote the following function:

```
private static String getExternalStoragePath(Context mContext) {
    StorageManager mStorageManager = (StorageManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    Class<?> storageVolumeClazz = null;
    try {
        storageVolumeClazz = Class.forName("android.os.storage.StorageVolume");
        Method getVolumeList = mStorageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumeList");
        Method getPath = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getPath");
        Method isRemovable = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("isRemovable");
        Object result = getVolumeList.invoke(mStorageManager);
        final int length = Array.getLength(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Object storageVolumeElement = Array.get(result, i);
            String path = (String) getPath.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
            boolean removable = (Boolean) isRemovable.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
            if (removable == true) {
                return path;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and the following code to handle the file creation process,

```
...
String dirOtherApp = "/Android/data/com.other.application/";
String sdCardPath = getExternalStoragePath(context);
String fileName = "new_file.txt";
final File removableStorage = new File(sdCardPath + dirOtherApp + "/" + fileName);
...
```

but an error occurs with a log like this:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/4454-1BFB/Android/data/Android/data/com.other.application/new_file.txt (Permission denied)
```

I have no problem creating files in the directory "sdcard0" on the device, but it always fails when creating new files in the directory "scard1" / removable storage ( in case my card Id is 4454-1BFB. maybe... ).

I have the code for request permssion written in **KOTLIN** like this.

```
private val readStoragePermission: Int = 11
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private fun requestPhonePermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            readStoragePermission
        )
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            readStoragePermission
        )
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            readStoragePermission
        )
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
        )
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY),
            readStoragePermission
        )
    }
}
```

How can I create a new file on the removable storage? do I have to add code to the function request permission too ?, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Your app doesn't have permission to write into another app's internal storage. This is normal system behavior, and I don't believe there's a workaround. More info: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help